# Easiest way to setup MongoDB sharded cluster

Tags: mongodb, testing, admin, sharding

What is the easiest way to setup a sharded cluster with MongoDB?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Start the mongo shell without connecting to a database:

```
 mongo --nodb
```

Then start a new sharding test specifying the number of mongos and shards that you would like:

```
 new ShardingTest({ shards: 2, mongos: 1 })
```

The logging output from each of the processes will be piped to this single shell (so there will be a lot). This makes that shell somewhat unusable but at least it only takes up one window and spares you from having to fork and specify a log path.

Just open up another shell and you are ready to go. Connect to the first mongos on port 30999.